# Access endpoints from WSO2 GREG

Tags: wso2, wso2-as, wso2-governance-registry

I have JAX WS applications created and deployed on WSO2 Application server. and service endpoints are registered into WSO2 GREG. Now I want to make use of these endpoints into web application which are also deployed into same Application server.
To do this I have mounted the GREG registry into Application Server now I want to know the best way to use these registry resource from java code. I read some documentation but too much confusion about which one to choose.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the recommended way to achieve this is using [governance REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance540/Governance+REST+API). Other than that I assume you can use a [registry client](https://dzone.com/articles/access-wso2-registry) as well. Since it is overriding the governance capabilities I would not recommend it.

hope this helps.